# passing allocated pointer before it allocated

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm studying the open source project *ROS*. While I saw the strange code.

```
Server server(n, "do_dishes", boost::bind(&execute, _1, &server), false);
```

The variable **server** is used before it's allocated as **server**. Is that possible? At least, my visual studio 2010 compiler doesn't understand that style of code. Please let me know if that is really possible code, or not.

original document of the code : http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib#C.2B-.2B-_SimpleActionServer

---

--------- Added

Thank you for your kindness. However I got "'server' : undeclared identifier" error when i compile it. so I tested simple code.

```
class TestCls {
public:
    TestCls(TestCls *aa)
    {

    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TestCls tt(&tt);

}
```

It also makes the same error. "'tt' : undeclared identifier".
am I missing something? please help me.

Comment: This looks like a bug with your compiler. It should compile. [G++ example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5dc8e8ff6b70059), [Clang++ example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e238b2e6abc2f93b).

Comment: okay. it seems MS visual studio 2010 cannot compile this. thank you Mankarse. thank you Bill Gates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is legal. Variables are in scope immediately when they are declared. This rule exists to enable self-referential data-structures to be constructed in a single line. The pointer can point to a non-constructed object, as long as it is not dereferenced before that object is constructed.

Since the pointer is being passed into the `Server` constructor, this will work, as long as `Server` correctly waits before calling the function object.

Comment: Thank you Mankarse. I added further question. please help me